# Short Forms Considerations

Tags: word-usage, usage

1) When I was taking an English course, the teacher once corrected me saying:

*You shouldn't write **don't**, write **do not***!

Since then, I only write **don't** in informal cases: email to a friend, here, etc. 

Do you think is it all right to write **don't** in a cover letter (for instance)? 

Shall we write **Do not** if we want to make a good impression as saying that we have an excellent level of English, or all of this doesn't matter?

2) Another question is about the usage of **Would like** and **'d like**.
In grammars and websites about English language on internet they always say:

> **I Would like = I'd like**

Then, when is the time to give examples they use **'d like** in most cases.

*E.g **I'd like** a cup of tea*

Today I was doing a grammar exercise and the key answers usually have alternatives to include short forms - has not (or hasn't) etc. - but for **would like** there were not alternatives, the answer should be **'d like**. 

Is it old-fashioned to write:

*I **would like** a cup of tea* (?)

Comment: Yes, in formal writing, you should avoid using contractions. The **'d** may be *would* or *had*. 'I would like a cup of tea' is not old-fashioned; it is subjunctive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This question has been asked [before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/are-contractions-like-didnt-forbidden-in-written-english)

2) It's not always correct to avoid contractions (yes even in formal writing). A cautious and sensible approach to use of contractions is recommended. Here are some links that can help

http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/questions-and-quandaries/grammar/can-i-use-contractions-in-my-writing

http://www.vappingo.com/word-blog/when-is-it-okay-to-use-contractions-in-formal-writing/